Live stream mpeg2-ts is stuck using mpegts.js library (playing in Chrome browser on PC)
I have a camera that writes a live video file into the disk (by capture card), the file has .m2t ending and is basically a MPEG2-TS stream. I need to play it live in web browser, the video should be in sync with the live stream. I try to use mpegts.js library for this, it is based on MSE (Media Source Extensions technology).
The problem is, the video jumps to the current time point & gets stuck there from the beginning, I get **onSourceClose ** event from _mediaSource right away, even though the file continues to grow as streaming progresses.
Those are the setting that I initialize mpegts.js player with:
  var player = Mpegts.createPlayer(
        {
          type: "m2ts", 
          isLive: true,
          url: myFileURL, //.m2t live file
          hasVideo: true
        },
        {
          accurateSeek: true,
          liveBufferLatencyChasing: true, 
          liveBufferLatencyChasingOnPaused: true,
          liveSync: true,
          enableStashBuffer: true,
          stashInitialSize: 500000,
        }
      );

